# MBProgressHUD is not working with NSNotificationCenter

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I am using `NSnotificationCenter` for example.
I am visiting detailscreen of feed from FeedList,
there I am deleting that feed,
after deleting that feed I am adding notification and poping controller to return on FeedList Screen.
There, I am reloading FeedList so while reloading I want to display `ProgressHud` for preventing user to do anything.
But it is not working. I am using `MBProgresHud.Show()` also I tried for `MBProgressHUD.ShowWhileExecuting()`. But both methods are not working.
Please suggest any solution for same.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this method instead..

Show

```
 [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
 [MBProgressHUD HUDForView:self.view].labelText = @"Reloading data...";
```

Hide

```
 [MBProgressHUD hideAllHUDsForView:self.view animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add message in main window,

like this...

```
#inclide "AppDelegate.h"


AppDelegate *Maindelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:Maindelegate.window animated:YES];
[MBProgressHUD HUDForView:self.view].labelText = @"Reloading data...";
```

Plesase chk this code is working or not

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer that was due to PopViewController.